# how to create same copy of pdf in same pdf document

Tags: c#, pdfsharp

IN my program user passes the input as number of copies.

So if user passes number of copies as 2 then i want to generate single pdf document with same pages repeating twice

I am using PdfSharp  library

I have below code which creates pdf document with multiple pages

```
var document = new PdfDocument();
var page = document.AddPage();
var gfx = XGraphics.FromPdfPage(page);
page.Width = XUnit.FromMillimeter(111);
page.Height = XUnit.FromMillimeter(222);
//some logic to create multiple pages
document.Save("C:\mydoc\");
```

I am sure we need to add loop but what more i need to do to have same copies repeating in same document as per input provided

**Update**

Lets say document generated 2 pages and user says number of copies 2 then that single pdf document will now have 4 page with 2 pages repeating twice in same document:

pagecontent1 pagecontent 2, pagecontent1,pagecontent2

**Update 2**

i tried @Christophers solution and changed code like below before i save document

```
PdfDocument outputDocument = new PdfDocument();
for (int i = 0; i < PageCopies; i++)
        {
            //the loop doing the copies
            for (int k = 0; k < document.Pages.Count; k++)
            {
                outputDocument.Pages.Add(document.Pages[k]);

            }
        }
```

But now i get error **a pdf document must be opened with pdfdocumentopenmode.import to import pages from it**

Comment: Are we talking about PageContent1, PageContent2, PageContent1, PageContent2? Or PageContent1, PageContent1, PageContent2, PageContent2

Comment: you want to make copies of certain pages as a separate pdf?

Comment: @christopher pagecontent1 pagecontent 2, pagecontent1,pagecontent2

Comment: @kixoka i want copy of certain pages in same pdf

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally I managed to resolve myself but of course due to clues from @Christopher and @Blaise.

Here is my final code:

```
var document = new PdfDocument();
var page = document.AddPage();
var gfx = XGraphics.FromPdfPage(page);
page.Width = XUnit.FromMillimeter(111);
page.Height = XUnit.FromMillimeter(222);
//some logic to create multiple pages
document.Save(@"C:\mydoc\");

    PdfDocument finalOutputDocument;
    if (CopyCount > 1) {
      MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream();
      document.Save(stream, false);
      PdfDocument source = PdfReader.Open(stream, PdfDocumentOpenMode.Import);

      finalOutputDocument = new PdfDocument();

      for (int i = 0; i < CopyCount; i++) {
        for (int k = 0; k < document.Pages.Count; k++) {
          finalOutputDocument.Pages.Add(source.Pages[k]);
        }
      }
    } else {
      finalOutputDocument = document;
    }

    finalOutputDocument.Save(path);
```

Answer (score 2):

If I understand correctly, I think you could save your original Complete PDF, then open and merge it multiple times.

If that is so, this may be close. I've combined your code with some documentation from pdfsharp found here: http://www.pdfsharp.net/wiki/ConcatenateDocuments-sample.ashx

```
var document = new PdfDocument();
var page = document.AddPage();
var gfx = XGraphics.FromPdfPage(page);
page.Width = XUnit.FromMillimeter(111);
page.Height = XUnit.FromMillimeter(222);
//some logic to create multiple pages
document.Save("OriginalDoc.pdf");

//Logic here to open and merge the document multiple times
PdfDocument outputDocument = new PdfDocument();

// Open the document to import pages from it.
PdfDocument inputDocument = PdfReader.Open("C:\mydoc\OriginalDoc.pdf", PdfDocumentOpenMode.Import);

  for(int i = 0; i < Copies; i++)
  {
    // Iterate pages
    int count = inputDocument.PageCount;
    for (int idx = 0; idx < count; idx++)
    {
      // Get the page from the external document...
      PdfPage page = inputDocument.Pages[idx];
      // ...and add it to the output document.
      outputDocument.AddPage(page);
    }
  }
  // Save the document...
  const string filename = "MergedDoc.pdf";
  outputDocument.Save(filename);
```

I suspect this could be done without saving and re-opening the document as well, but I haven't used pdfsharp myself.

Comment: is it possible that we dont save document at first instance and just use instance of document variable and then do whole merge operation and finally save one single document?

Comment: I suspect yes, but I'm not familiar with PDFSharp and what might happen to the internal state of the objects as they are used. I would try doing it without saving the first document and see what happens.

Comment: Did you give this a try? I see your update you ran into an error that the document must be opened in Import mode, this method uses Import mode.

Answer (score 1):

Okay, the propblem turned out to be very different from what I first understood. As I have no expierience with PDFSharp in particular, I can only help with the general loop structure.

```
//I use a array to simulate the input PDF
int[] input = new int[]{ 1, 2 };
//And a list to simulate the output PDF
List<int> output = new List<int>();

//PageCopies is set somewhere outside this code.
//The loop counting the copies
for(int i = 0; i < PageCopies; i++){
  //the loop doing the copies
  for(int k = 0; k < input.Count; k++){
    output.Add(input[k]);
  }
}
```

Dislcaimer: Code not run against a compiler. Syntax and off by one errors reserved